How to put ones in random places in matrix (or 2D array) of zeroes in C++
I wanted to create a 9x9 matrix with 10 ones in it, which is filled randomly in C/C++.
For example, it should look like this:
array[[ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, ]
      [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ]
      [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ]
      [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, ]
      [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, ]
      [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ]
      [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, ]
      [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ]
      [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, ]]


What have you done to learn C++, this is a very basic thing to do and you could have picked it up after a few hours of effort (learncpp.com)

The question was closed before I could answer. The answer really depends on what you mean by random, for example if there is any constrain of biased probability regarding columns or row. In the simples way you need to flatten the elements and shuffle the ten ones, https://godbolt.org/z/9dEWc5x5Y

The core of the problem is to pick a random subset of a given range, in a way that all possible subsets are equally likely. This is what library function std::sample() does for you. See comment under the accepted answer.

There are different ways. You could fill the 10 first positions in an array with 1s and then call std::shuffle to put those in random positons. You could also create a list of available positions and randomly pick 10 out of that list.
Commented example of the former:
#include <algorithm>  // shuffle
#include <array>      // array
#include <iostream>   //
#include <random>     // mt19937

int main() {
    constexpr unsigned side_size = 9;
    // a seeded pseudo number generator
    std::mt19937 prng(std::random_device{}());

    std::array<std::array<int, side_size>, side_size> arr_to_fill;
    unsigned ones = 10;  // the number of 1's we want

    // create an array with all available positions number from 0-
    std::array<unsigned, side_size * side_size> positions{};

    // put 1's in the first `ones` positions:
    std::fill_n(positions.begin(), ones, 1);

    // shuffle the array so the 1's are put in random positions
    std::shuffle(positions.begin(), positions.end(), prng);   

    // fill the array:
    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < positions.size(); ++idx) {
        arr_to_fill[idx / side_size][idx % side_size] = positions[idx];
    }

    // print result:
    for (auto& inner : arr_to_fill) {
        for (auto v : inner) std::cout << ' ' << v;
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

Demo
(Note that it's tempting to just cast the 2d array into a plain 1d array and fill that with 1's and shuffle it directly but then you are in undefined behavior territory)

Commented example of the latter:
#include <array>    // array
#include <iostream> // 
#include <numeric>  // iota
#include <random>   // mt19937, uniform_int_distribution

int main() {
    constexpr unsigned side_size = 9;
    // a seeded pseudo number generator
    std::mt19937 prng(std::random_device{}());

    // all zeroes:
    std::array<std::array<int, side_size>, side_size> arr_to_fill{};
    unsigned ones = 10;  // the number of 1's we want

    // create an array with all available positions number from 0-
    std::array<unsigned, side_size * side_size> positions;
    std::iota(positions.begin(), positions.end(), 0);  // [0, side_size^2)

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < ones; ++i) {
        unsigned last = positions.size() - 1 - i;  // last unpicked pos
        // distribution of random numbers from 0 to last (inclusive)
        std::uniform_int_distribution dist(0u, last);

        unsigned idx = dist(prng);         // get random index ...
        unsigned pos = positions[idx];     // ... to pick a position
        positions[idx] = positions[last];  // copy last unpicked position

        // put a 1 in the chosen positions place:
        arr_to_fill[pos / side_size][pos % side_size] = 1;
    }
    // print result:
    for (auto& inner : arr_to_fill) {
        for (auto v : inner) std::cout << ' ' << v;
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

Demo

If you can use external libraries, you could also simplify this by using boost::multi::array.
Example provided by alfC:
#include <multi/array.hpp> // boost::multi::array

#include <algorithm>  // shuffle
#include <iostream>   //
#include <random>     // mt19937

int main() {
    std::mt19937 prng(std::random_device{}());

    // create a 9x9 array, initialized with 0's:
    boost::multi::array<int, 2> A({9, 9}, 0);

    // fill the first 10 elements:
    std::fill_n(A.elements().begin(), 10, 1);

    // shuffle the array so the 1's end up in random positions:
    std::shuffle(A.elements().begin(), A.elements().end(), prng);

    // print result:
    for (auto const& row : A) {
        for (auto const& v : row) {
            std::cout << ' ' << v;
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

Demo

Array libraries do need a flattened views for these things: https://godbolt.org/z/9dEWc5x5Y

@alfC Yes, that is seriously much nicer with boost::multi::array or a similar home made 1d array wrapper.

Regarding efficiency, it is possible to minimize the number of relatively expensive random “draws” by using library function std::sample() compared to plain std::shuffle(). Something like: std::sample(positions.begin(), positions.end(), std::back_inserter(toBeSetToOne), 10, prng); You had initialized the whole matrix at zero, and finally set to 1 just those matrix elements whose indices ended up in your toBeSetToOne vector.

@jpmarinier I'm not sure std::sample is the right tool here. At least not used like that since it performs worse than both my two top suggestions: https://quick-bench.com/q/9gzf-IzBzDTO_4sXhCR-9QDg7nE
